# Chunking array more efficiently?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Just trying to find out if there is a more efficient way of chunking an array; I have an array that could be rather large, and I need to chunk it into multidimensional arrays of **3**, but only have **4**.

This is what I have so far, and it works; but the question is to see if there is a better/faster alternative.

```
$rows = array_chunk($array, 3);

$top = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $top[] = $rows[$i];
}
```

#### Notes

The `$rows` array looks something like this:

```
array(
    [0] => name,
    [1] => name,
    [2] => name,
    .....etc
)
```

And I'd just like to chunk it to look like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [0] => name,
        [1] => name,
        [2] => name,
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [0] => name,
        [1] => name,
        [2] => name,
    ),
    [2] => array(
        [0] => name,
        [1] => name,
        [2] => name,
    ),
    [3] => array(
        [0] => name,
        [1] => name,
        [2] => name,
    )
)
```

*And for those who don't bother reading, I* **do** *already have something that works (as stated above), I'm just trying to optimize it as it's quite possibly the ugliest way to do it.*

Comment: where does the array come from?

Comment: @Dagon the array comes from a function that itterates a directory for the first-level file names.

Comment: `and I need to chunk it into multidimensional arrays of 3, but only have 4` That means fixed 4 elements on main array with 3 sub elements on each? That means your original array will always be size 12 or more? and we have to disregard all the values after the first 12?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That's exactly right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//make sure to copy the sliced values into a different array
$slice = array_slice($array,0,12);
$rows = array_chunk($slice,3);
```

Comment: `foreach(range(0,3) as $i) {` - in php it looks ugly :-)

Comment: Slice then chunk seems to be the obvious way to go

Comment: I think the solution which you have given as an alternative `OR` is by far the best. Probably that should be your primary answer. I will delete my answer for that. +1 for that `OR` part